# Why do NSS modules have to end in .so.2 on Linux?

Tags: linux, strace, nss

I've built a Name Service Switch Module for Red Hat Linux.

Using strace, I've determined that the OS looks for the library in various directories, but only for files with the extension `.so.2`  (e.g. `libnss_xxx.so.2`, where `xxx` is the service name)

Why doesn't it look for `.so` or `.so.1` libraries? Is there any guarantee that it won't stop looking for `.so.2` libraries and start looking for `.so.3` libraries in future?

**EDIT**: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html, says that the `2` is 'a version number that is incremented whenever the interface changes'.
So I guess that:

- The version of NSS requires version 2 of the libraries.
- An OS update with an updated NSS might require a different version number.

Can someone confirm whether that is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assumption is generally true with a minor edit:

- The version of NSS requires a **version of the libraries with interface version 2**.
- An OS update with an updated NSS might require a different version number.

The version of an interface does not necessarily need to change with the version of the library, i.e. a newer version of the library might still provide the same interface.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of so files: shared libraries (loaded and scanned for symbols at compile time, loaded again and linked at program startup time) and modules (loaded and linked at run time). The idea of shared libraries is that your program requires a certain version of the library. This version is determined at compile time. Once the program is compiled, it should continue to work even if a new (incompatible) version of the library is installed. This means that the new version must be a different file, so old programs can still use the old library while newer (or more recently compiled) programs use the newer version.

To properly use this system, your program must somehow make sure that the library version it needs will continue to be installed. This is one of the tasks of a distribution's packaging system. The package containing your program must have a dependency on the required version of the library package.

However, you seem to be talking about modules. Things are different there. They do not carry such a version, because ld.so (which takes care of loading shared libraries) isn't the one loading them. Your program should be bundled with those modules, so the module versions are always compatible with the program using them. This works for most programs.

But it doesn't work if your program allows third party modules. So they can come up with their own versioning system. This seems to be what nss has done (I'm not familiar with it, though). This means that they have defined a protocol version (currently 2), which specifies what a module should look like: which symbols need to be defined, what arguments do functions expect, these sort of things. If you create a module following version 2 of the protocol, you should name your module .so.2 (because that's their way of checking your supported version). If they create a new incompatible protocol 3, they will start looking for .so.3. Your module will no longer be found, and that's a good thing, because it will also not support the new protocol.